# complexity in html css

Tags: html, css

my html code is

```
<tr class="links">
    <td>

        <table cellpadding = 0 cellspacing = 1 border = 0>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="home.php">Home</a></td>
                <td><a href="zakaria/products.php">Products</a></td> 
                <td><a href="zakaria/registration.php">Register</a></td>
                <td><a href="zakaria/login.php">LogIn</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the css code is

```
.links
    {
background-color: #BBBBDD;
text-align: center;
    }
```

but this time the links are showing in the left side. I want to show them i the center and give some space between the links. how can I do this.

Comment: You need to quit using tables for layout. Use `div` for containers (you can also use new tags in HTML5) and `ul` [unordered lists] for menus and stuff. If you want to stay with tables then wrap your inner or child table in a div and try centering it within the parent table row.

Comment: Also check this: http://prntscr.com/7u8pod

Answer (score 1):

You could tidy your code up, but the margin-left and margin-right is the key (run snippet)

```css
.links {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #BBBBDD;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="links" width="50%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 border=0>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="home.php">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="zakaria/products.php">Products</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="zakaria/registration.php">Register</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="zakaria/login.php">LogIn</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please provide page link so i can have a look or at least provide more html/css. What's not working?

Comment: @RachelGallen maybe move your class "links" to the table element and it will work?

Comment: @Andrew i did that in the tidied up code. if he copies and pastes the code it will work

Comment: @RachelGallen sorry wrong tag, its almost 5 in the morning here ...LOL